# Python - multiple embedded images in email - First one is embedded, the rest is attached, why?

Tags: python, email

I have the following code. But somehow only the first image is embedded. The rest of the images is attached to the email. Also, the plain text is not displayed.

Can you help me?

```
def create_msg2(img_list):
    msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
    # Set the email subject.
    msgRoot['Subject'] = 'This email contain both Html, text and images.'
    # Set the email from email address.
    msgRoot['From'] = USER
    # Set the email to email address.
    msgRoot['To'] = TO
    # Set the multipart email preamble attribute value. Please refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html to learn more.
    msgRoot.preamble = '====================================================='
    # Create a 'alternative' MIMEMultipart object. We will use this object to save plain text format content.
    msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    # Attach the bove object to the root email message.
    msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)
    # Create a MIMEText object, this object contains the plain text content.
    msgText = MIMEText('This object contains the plain text content of this email.')
    # Attach the MIMEText object to the msgAlternative object.
    msgAlternative.attach(msgText)
    
    for img in img_list:
        image_cid = make_msgid()
        # Create a MIMEText object to contains the email Html content. There is also an image in the Html content. The image cid is image1.
        msgText = MIMEText('<br><img src="cid:{image_cid}"></br>'.format(image_cid=image_cid[1:-1]), 'html')
        # Attach the above html content MIMEText object to the msgAlternative object.
        msgAlternative.attach(msgText)
        # Open a file object to read the image file, the image file is located in the file path it provide.
        with open(img, 'rb') as f:
        # Create a MIMEImage object with the above file object.
            msgImage = MIMEImage(f.read())
            
        # Add 'Content-ID' header value to the above MIMEImage object to make it refer to the image source (src="cid:image1") in the Html content.
        msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', image_cid)
        # Attach the MIMEImage object to the email body.
        msgRoot.attach(msgImage)

    return msgRoot
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this works now. The key is to attach the html string only once

```
def create_msg(img_list):
    msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')

    today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    msgRoot['Subject'] = f'Schlagzeilen, {today}'
    msgRoot['From'] = USER
    msgRoot['To'] = TO
    
    # Set the multipart email preamble attribute value. Please refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html to learn more.
    msgRoot.preamble = '====================================================='
    
    # Create a 'alternative' MIMEMultipart object. We will use this object to save plain text format content.
    msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)
    
    
    msgText = '<html><body><h1>Schlagzeilen</h1><br>'
    for img in img_list:
        image_cid = make_msgid()
        
        msgText += '<img src="cid:{image_cid}"><br>'.format(image_cid=image_cid[1:-1])
        
        # Open a file object to read the image file
        with open(img, 'rb') as f:
            msgImage = MIMEImage(f.read())
            
        # Add 'Content-ID' header value to the above MIMEImage object to make it refer to the image source in the Html content.
        msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', image_cid)
        msgRoot.attach(msgImage)
        
    msgText += '</body></html>'
    msgAlternative.attach(MIMEText(msgText, 'html'))
    
    return msgRoot
```